# Merge the two tags: tests and exam

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderation

We have two tags: [tests](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tests) and [exam](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exam). They both have wiki and the discussions there are semantically similar (exam is more complete). These should likely be merged.

I suggest (and Gypsy Spellweaver agrees -- it came from him, actually), that the tag should probably be "exams" a plural form to match other tags here. The other tag (say, tests) should be a synonym for "exams". All existing questions (15 currently) should be made to reflect the change.

Making it "exams" rather than "tests" makes it clear that the tag isn't about software testing, but about evaluation of students.

Moderator intervention is needed since "exams" can't be created by an ordinary user as it is "too close" to the existing tag.

Answer (score 2):

These are ultimately both forms of assessment. Why not put everything under that tag? I would argue that merging everything into that tag would make for a more comprehensive database of related questions rather than splintering the two. Every exam is an assessment. While I wouldn't challenge this merging, I would suggest that we take it a step further.

Comment: See my comment on the assessments meta post. I don't agree that it should all be merged.